# How to install the searchkick gem when using cloud9 online IDE

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, cloud9-ide, searchkick

I am following [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DR5JLZ2Qgg&index=5&list=PL23ZvcdS3XPLNdRYB_QyomQsShx59tpc-) where we want to add a search functionality to the app. But when I run `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Movie` in the terminal I get

```
rake aborted!
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/faraday-
Tasks: TOP => searchkick:reindex
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Is there any other way to get around this when using an online IDE? I think this only happens to those who use online editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searchkick is a gem that works with elasticsearch. Maybe you need to install elasticsearch first or run it if you have already installed.

You can check how to setup elasticsearch in the following [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html):

Comment: I have elastic search installed. Can't see why 'rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Movie' wont work now that I get 'Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200'

Comment: sorry noticed I had not installed elastic search correctly. I uninstalled what i had then made a fresh install

Answer (score 1):

To make [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) working on [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) you have to execute elasticseach first.

Even if `searchkick` gem install the dependencies of `elasticsearch` it is not enought (at least for Cloud9). You have to install it manually and execute it.

You can find the latest version on [the official website](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch). And execute these commands on your terminal:

```
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-VERSION.zip
unzip elasticsearch-VERSION.zip
cd elasticsearch-VERSION
./bin/elasticsearch&
```

To check if everythings if working well, `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'` should returns a `"status" : 200`.

To stop the server, you can use the RESTful API:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/_local/_shutdown'
```